# Tell if a user has liked a blog post

Tags: 2013, blog

How does SharePoint keep track of if a user has liked a blog post or not?  I'm thinking it must be a property either on the post or on the user.  Does anyone know how to programmatically find this info in Visual Studio?

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using ?

Comment: SharePoint Server

Comment: I think he meant; 2007, 2010, 2013?

Comment: Oh sorry, SharePoint Server 2013

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/take-your-sharepoint-social-features-to-the-next-level-with-i-like-it-and-tags-counters-part-3.aspx) should get you started, to the best of my knowledge the code behind call to SocialTagManager hasn't changed from 2010 to 2013, but I could be wrong.